# Positioning this automaton in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, automata

the following question might seem very much like a duplicate, but unfortunately I cannot figure it out myself:

In the following MWE, I try to have the automaton in the upper right corner. I very much suspect that this is possible with inserting a node and using "remember" and "overlay", but unfortunately I am still missing the right combination of them to make it work.

Would anybody be so kind to help me out on that?
Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]{Minimal consistent automata ($ |\Sigma| \geq 2 $)}
    \begin{block}{}
        The plan: \textbullet  construction of a sample which provokes $ \geq 3 $ states
    \end{block}
%           \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%                       \node[opacity=1,xshift=5.5cm,yshift=3cm,at=(current page.center)] {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                                [scale = 0.4, transform shape,
                                -> , >= stealth,
                                shorten >=0pt ,
                                node distance =2.5 cm ,
                                initial text = ,
                                semithick ]
                                \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \varepsilon $};
                                \node[state, accepting] (q2) [right = 2cm of q1]{$ 0 $};
                                \path[->] 
                                (q1) edge [below] node {0} (q2)
                                (q1) edge [loop above] node {1} (q1)
                                (q2) edge [loop above] node {1} (q2)
                                (q2) edge [bend right = 15, above] node {0} (q1)
                                ;
%                       };  
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your figure in a node located in the upper right corner.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{beamer}  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]{Minimal consistent automata ($ |\Sigma| \geq 2 $)}
    \begin{block}{}
        The plan: \textbullet  construction of a sample which provokes $ \geq 3 $ states
    \end{block}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-10pt,yshift=-5pt]  at (current page.north east){%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [scale = 0.4, transform shape,
            -> , >= stealth,
            shorten >=0pt ,
            node distance =2.5 cm ,
            initial text = ,
            semithick ]
            \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \varepsilon $};
            \node[state, accepting] (q2) [right = 2cm of q1]{$ 0 $};
            \path[->] 
            (q1) edge [below] node {0} (q2)
            (q1) edge [loop above] node {1} (q1)
            (q2) edge [loop above] node {1} (q2)
            (q2) edge [bend right = 15, above] node {0} (q1); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        };
   \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata, 
                positioning,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Minimal consistent automata ($ |\Sigma| \geq 2 $)}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.65\textwidth}
The plan: 
    \begin{itemize}
\item   construction of a sample which provokes $ \geq 3 $ states
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, scale = 0.5, transform shape,
node distance=22mm,
initial text = ,
semithick,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, shorten >=1pt}
                      ]
\node[state, initial]   (q1) {$ \varepsilon $};
\node[state, accepting,
      right=of q1]      (q2) {$0$};
%
\path   (q1)    edge[loop above, "1"]  ()
                edge["0"]               (q2)
        (q2)    edge [loop above, "1"]  ()
                edge [bend right,"0" '] (q1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata, 
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Minimal consistent automata ($ |\Sigma| \geq 2 $)
        \hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
auto, scale = 0.4, transform shape,
node distance=22mm,
initial text = ,
semithick,
color=black,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, shorten >=1pt}
                      ]
\node[state, initial]   (q1) {$ \varepsilon $};
\node[state, accepting,
      right=of q1]      (q2) {$0$};
%
\path   (q1)    edge[loop above, "1"]  ()
                edge["0"]               (q2)
        (q2)    edge [loop above, "1"]  ()
                edge [bend right,"0" '] (q1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
                }
The plan: 
    \begin{itemize}
\item   construction of a sample which provokes $ \geq 3 $ states
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can use absolute positioning as explained in the [TikZ/PGf manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) section 13.2.2, page 134, for v1.8.

I think it's easiest to place node q2 first relative to the upper right corner of the page, since it's closer to that corner, then put q1 to the left of it, rather than putting q2 to the right of q1.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]{Minimal consistent automata ($ |\Sigma| \geq 2 $)}
    \begin{block}{}
        The plan: \textbullet\  construction of a sample which provokes $ \geq 3 $ states
    \end{block}
            \hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                                scale = 0.4, transform shape,
                                -> , >= stealth,
                                shorten >=0pt ,
                                node distance =2.5 cm ,
                                initial text = ,
                                semithick ]
                                \node[state, accepting] (q2) [ below left = 3cm of current page.north east ] {$ 0 $};
                                \node[state, initial] (q1) [left = 2cm of q2] {$ \varepsilon $};
                                \path[->]
                                (q1) edge [below] node {0} (q2)
                                (q1) edge [loop above] node {1} (q1)
                                (q2) edge [loop above] node {1} (q2)
                                (q2) edge [bend right = 15, above] node {0} (q1)
                                ;
%                       };  
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Of course you play around with exactly where you want it.

[image: automata diagram in upper right]